# How to explain displayed value for os.FileMode?

Tags: go

I have a program trying to filter NamedPipe files. Since it didn’t work as expected, I printed the result but was surprised by the output. Can you explain it?

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, info := range files {
        log.Printf("file: %s mode: %x\n", info.Name(), info.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe)
        log.Printf("file: %s mode: %v\n", info.Name(), info.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe)
        log.Printf("file: %s mode: %v\n", info.Name(), info.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe != 0)
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: main.go mode: 2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: main.go mode: ----------
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: main.go mode: false
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: status.kch mode: 702d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: status.kch mode: p---------
2020/02/06 18:06:46 file: status.kch mode: true
```

What I don’t understand is the output when I print the Mode in hexadecimal. I expected the Mode to be a bit set and os.ModeNamedPipe to be a bit mask. So I assumed that `info.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe` would yield the integer 0 when the file is not a named pipe. But I get a different value.

I finally found out how to test if the file is a named pipe, but it is counter-intuitive.

Could you explain these different outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`info.Mode()` returns a value of type [`os.FileMode`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode), and `os.ModeNamedPipe` is also of type `os.FileMode`. So this will be the type of the value you want to print / log.

`os.FileMode` is not "just" an integer type, it's a distinct type and it implements [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer). And printing it with the `%x` verb, the rules from the [package doc](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

So the `FileMode.String()` method will be called first, and then the string value will be printed using `%x`, which means:

> String and slice of bytes (treated equivalently with these verbs):
>
> ```
> %x    base 16, lower-case, two characters per byte
> ```

So what you see (`2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d`) is the hexa representation of the (UTF-8) bytes of the string representation of the resulting `os.FileMode`. It's either "full of dashes" if it's not a named pipe, otherwise it has a leading `'p'`.

You may convert it to integer (`uint32`) if you want to see it as a number (yes, `os.ModeNamedPipe` only has a single bit set):

```
fmt.Printf("as-is         : %x\n", os.ModeNamedPipe)
fmt.Printf("hexa string   : %x\n", os.ModeNamedPipe.String())
fmt.Printf("default string: %v\n", os.ModeNamedPipe.String())
fmt.Printf("decimal       : %d\n", os.ModeNamedPipe)
fmt.Printf("hexa          : %x\n", uint32(os.ModeNamedPipe))
fmt.Printf("binary        : %b\n", os.ModeNamedPipe)
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ixWiGP4w11L)):

```
as-is         : 702d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
hexa string   : 702d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
default string: p---------
decimal       : 33554432
hexa          : 2000000
binary        : 10000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

`info.Mode()` returns a `os.FileMode`, which has a `String` method:

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode.String

The output of the `String` method is like:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

When you & the filemode with named pipe mask, you get zero, which is

```
----------
```

and 2d is a `-`, which explains the 2d2d2d2d output.

It appears like while formatting for %x, printf tries to see if it is one of the types it recognizes. Since it is not (a FileMode) and it has a String() method, it first converts it to string.